# Passing variables to cp / mv

Tags: bash

I can use the cp or mv command to copy/mv files to a new folder manually but while in a for loop, it fails.

I've tried various ways of doing this and none seem to work. The most frustrating part is it works when run locally.

A simple version of what I'm trying to do is shown below:

```sh
#!bin/bash

#Define path variables
source_dir=/home/me/loop
destination_dir=/home/me/loop/new

#Change working dir
cd "$source_dir"

#Step through source_dir for each .txt. file
for f in *.txt
  do
    # If the txt file was modified within the last 300 minutes...
    if [[ $(find "$f" -mmin -300) ]]
    then
    # Add breaks for any spaces in filenames
    f="${f// /\\ }"
    # Copy file to destination
    cp "$source_dir/$f $destination_dir/"
    fi
  done
```

Error message is:

```sh
cp: missing destination file operand after '/home/me/loop/first\ second.txt /home/me/loop/new/'
Try 'cp --help' for more information.
```

However, I can manually run:

```sh
mv /home/me/loop/first\ second.txt /home/me/loop/new/
```

and it works fine. 
I get the same error using cp and similar errors using rsync so I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong...

Comment: These are two arguments not one. Not `cp "$source_dir/$f $destination_dir/"` but `cp "$source_dir/$f" "$destination_dir/"`. And what do you do with spaces? Remove the `f="${f// /\\ }"`. Also the `[[ $(find "$f" -mmin -300) ]]` is strange, at least quote it. Can't you just `while IFS= read -r file; do .... ; done < <(find "$source_dir" -min 300 -type f -name '*.txt')`? Or better yet just `find "$source_dir" -min 300 -name '*.txt' -type f | xargs -i cp {} "$destination_dir"`.

Comment: Or even `find "$source_dir" -mmin 300 -type f -name '*.txt' -exec cp -t "$target_dir" {} +`

Comment: End options of the `cp` command with `--`: `find "$source_dir" -mmin 300 -type f -name '*.txt' -exec cp -t "$target_dir" -- {} +`

Answer (score 2):

> ```
> cp "$source_dir/$f $destination_dir/"
> ```

When you surround both arguments with double quotes you turn them into one argument with an embedded space. Quote them separately.

```
cp "$source_dir/$f" "$destination_dir/"
```

There's no do anything special for spaces beforehand. The quoting already ensures files with whitespace are handled correctly.

```
# Add breaks for any spaces in filenames
f="${f// /\\ }"
```

Let's take a step back, though. Looping over all `*.txt` files and then checking each one with `find` is overly complicated. `find` already loops over multiple files and does arbitrary things to those files. You can do everything in this script in a single `find` command.

```
#!bin/bash

source_dir=/home/me/loop
destination_dir=/home/me/loop/new

find "$source_dir" -name '*.txt' -mmin -300 -exec cp -t "$destination_dir" {} +
```

Comment: The one line command has two disadvantages though, first off it can be hard to expand with more functionality, and it can easily become quite hard to read. It we remove the replacing spaces redundancy in the original example, I actually find the original code more readable than the one liner :)

Answer (score 1):

You need to divide it in to two strings, like this:

```sh
cp "$source_dir/$f" "$destination_dir/"
```

by having as one you are basically telling cp that the entire line is the first parameter, where it is actually two (source and destination).

Edit: As @kamil-cuk and @aaron states there are better ways of doing what you try to do. Please read their comments

Comment: For safety of commands working on files or paths provided as variables, always terminate the options with `--` . Ex.: `cp -- "${source_dir}/${f}" "${destination_dir}/"`. Also think about using the `install` command that may handle copy more explicitly than `cp`.